# neo4j batch-import file not found error

Tags: import, neo4j, graph-databases

I tried to use the batch-import from [maxdemarzi](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1). I have followed these steps, however it gives error when i tried to compile it with 'javac ./src/test/java/TestDataGenerator.java -d .' It gives file not found error. I have found TestDataGenerator.java in other path and tried to compile. It gives error, too. I think sources are not up-to-date.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use maven to build it.

```
mvn clean install
```